# Identifying a space $X$ such that $\pi_1(X) = \langle \, a, b \; | \; a^2, b^2, (ab)^3 \, \rangle$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm looking to find a space which has the fundamental group $\pi_1(X) = \langle \, a, b \; | \; a^2, b^2, (ab)^3 \, \rangle$. Looking at Hatcher's AT, I see that any group may be a fundamental group -- and so I was curious if perhaps the $S_3$ symmetric group has a topological space to call its own.

I see that the real projective plane, $\mathbb{R}P^2$, has a fundamental group $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2) = \langle \, a \; | \; a^2 \, \rangle$, and so by van Kampen we have $$\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2 \vee \mathbb{R}P^2) = \pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2) \, \ast \,\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2) = \langle \, a, b \; | \; a^2, b^2 \, \rangle.$$

This gets us close, but I wonder if the space I am looking for is some adjunction space $\mathbb{R}P^2 \cup_\phi \mathbb{R}P^2$ but I am uncertain the choice of $\phi$. Or, am I completely off course?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick any simply connected space upon which $S_3$ acts freely and pass to the quotient. I'll construct an example for a larger group.

Let $n\geq5$. Let $V$ be the standard real representation of $S_{n+1}$ — this is the $n$-dimensional orthogonal complement of the diagonal in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, upon which $S_{n+1}$ acts by permutation of the coordinates. The standard inner product of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ is preserved by $S_{n+1}$. Let us restrict it to $V$, and let $S$ be the unit sphere in $V$. The group $S_{n+1}$ acts on $S$, but this is not a free action.

Let $SS$ be the set of all pairs $(p,v)$ with $p$ and $v$ two points in $S$ such that $p\perp v$. This is the unit tangent bundle to the sphere $S$. The action of $S_{n+1}$ on $V$ induces one on $SS$,and now this is a free one. One can compute that $\pi_1(SS)=1$ so the quotient $SS/S_{n+1}$ has fundamental group $S_{n+1}$.

---

The correct answer to your question is that every group $G$ has a space of its own: it is called the Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(G,1)$, which is characterized (up to homotopy equivalence) by the condition that it is path-connected, has fundamental group isomorphic to $G$ and all other homotopy groups trivial. If you google for that you'll find that there are literally books written about these spaces.

Usually these spaces are not very easy to visualize. For example, the circle $S^1$ is a $K(\mathbb Z,1)$, and the infinite real projective space $\mathbb RP^\infty$ is a $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z,1)$. The geometry of $K(G,1)$ gives a lot of information about the group $G$.

Answer (score 2):

This is really just a long comment: One can construct a space with a prescribed fundamental group as follows. Start with a point, and attach edges to the point for each generator. Then attach disks to the edges to create nullhomotopic loops for each relation you want in the fundamental group. For you, you want to add a disk that wraps around loops $a$ and $b$ twice, as well as one that wraps around $(ab)$ three times.

I don't think this is really the answer you want. I think the question you mean to ask is "is there a more familiar space I can construct with this fundamental group?" or maybe "can the space that is constructed in this way be recognized as some sort of gluing construction with more just a few simple, more familiar spaces?" I don't know the answer to this question, unfortunately.